# Windows Vista and 7 crossrealm authentication MIT Kerberos

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2008, kerberos

I'm using Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista and 7 for cross realm authentication using MIT Kerberos 1.6 but when i try to login with a user the KDC answers:

(wireshark output)

error_code: KRB5KDC_ERR_ETYPE_NOSUPP (14)
...
e-text: BAD_ENCRYPTION_TYPE

I want to know how can I change the encryption type method to be compatible with the KDC (i tried a XP client and it worked fine).

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean "export" to the hard drive? You can import from somewhere to get videos into the program you're using, but you can't improt to the drive.

Answer (score 1):

From the Windows 7 technical library: [Changes in Kerberos Authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560670%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Most likely, your Kerberos server is expecting DES encryption which has been disabled by default in Windows 7.  It has been replaced primarily by AES.  The linked article contains instructions for re-enabling DES encryption via group policy.  It's fairly simple.  But you should consider upgrading your Kerberos configuration to support AES instead.

Answer (score 0):

Which side is returning the bad crypto error?  Is it the Windows 7 client or the server?

Also, is it possible to try [Kerberos 1.7](http://web.mit.edu/Kerberos/krb5-1.7/)?  It was released about a month ago from MIT, it has some new configurable encryption settings for disabling weak crypto.